# What does it mean to use K-means clustering on a data set that indicates relative distances from one item to another?

Tags: python

what does it mean to use K-means clustering on a data set that indicates relative distances from one item to another?
For example, each item is given a relative distance to every other item.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

K-means clustering assigns items to clusters such that the total intra-cluster distance is minimized. Hence, the only input that is needed is a distance function `d(a,b)`. Often, the items are vectors in a normed vector space and `d` is chosen as `d(a,b) = ||a-b||` for some norm `||x||`. But in general, any distance function that fulfills `d(a,a) = 0` (distance from a point to itself is zero), `d(a,b) <= d(a,c) + d(c,b)` (triangle inequality), and `d(a,b) = d(b,a)` (symmetry) can be used. It can even be a matrix where the entry `M(i,j)` gives the distance between items `i` and `j`, as long as the entries obey the rules above.